# Data is not getting rendered on chart using chart.js in React (stacked bar chart)

Tags: json, reactjs, charts, chart.js, rest

My data is not getting rendered on chart. if I use **static data**, it will get rendered, but if I use data from my **rest api** (successfully retrieved data), I am getting **[object object]** in my chart.

My **App.cs**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import axios from 'axios'



class App extends Component {

constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  chartData: {}
}
}

componentDidMount() {
this.getChartData();
console.log('DRI YG WORKING---------' + this.state.chartData)

}

getChartData() {//DRI API
axios.get("https://taskmanagement.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path").then(res => {
  const coin = res.data;
  let labels = [];
  let datasets = [];
  coin.forEach(element => {
    labels.push(element.labels);
    datasets.push(element.datasets);

  });



  this.setState({
    chartData: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
    }
  });
  console.log('axiosssss chartData---------' + this.state.chartData)

  console.log('axiosssss datasetsss---------' + this.state.chartData.labels,       this.state.chartData.datasets)

  });
  }

  render() {

  const options = {
  tooltips: {
    displayColors: true,
    callbacks: {
      mode: 'x',
    },
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
      type: 'linear',
    }]
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: { position: 'bottom' },
}

return (
  <div className="App" >

    < div className="wrapper" >
      <Bar data={this.state.chartData} options={options} />


    </div>
  </div >
  );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

If i use this data, it will get rendered on my chart

```
   this.setState({
    chartData: {
      labels: ["nisa", "mk", "amir", "waqia", "jason", "william"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'In Progress',
        backgroundColor: "#caf270",
        data: [2, 5, 7, 8, 5, 4],
      }, {
        label: 'Completed',
        backgroundColor: "#45c490",
        data: [2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5],
      }, {
        label: 'Pending',
        backgroundColor: "#008d93",
        data: [4, 2, 6, 1, 4, 6],
      }]
    }
  })
```

in my getChartData is :

```
    [
   {
      "labels":{
         "0":"nisa",
         "1":"mk",
        "2": "amir",
        "3": "waqia",
        "4": "jason",
        "5":"william"
      },
      "datasets":[
         {
            " label":"In Progress",
            "backgroundColor":"#caf270",
          "data": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "5",
            "2": "7",
            "3": "8",
            "4": "5",
            "5": "4"
          }
         },
         {
            " label":"Completed",
            "backgroundColor":"#45c490",
          "data": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "3",
            "2": "7",
            "3": "5",
            "4": "2",
            "5": "4"
          }
         },
         {
            " label":"Pending",
            "backgroundColor":"#008d93",
          "data": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "3",
            "2": "2",
            "3": "1",
            "4": "2",
            "5": "4"
          }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am new to React.js, I really aprreciate for any help.. Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `chartData` in `getChartData`?

Comment: hi @ty. I have edit it in my question, please refer. Sorry for delay. Thank you